# Using custom font on webpage issue

Tags: html, css, font-face

I am not sure if I have defined these wrongs in the settings, but nothing seems to work

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: 'MyFont';
    src: url('http://kny.me/practice/fonts/tofinowide.woff2') format('woff2'), url('http://kny.me/practice/fonts/tofinowide.woff') format('woff'),

}

body {
    margin: 0px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
     font-family: 'MyFont', sans-serif, 'arial';

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the final comma from the end of the `src`. That works for me